# SSIS merge join only when left table has null columns

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, ssis

I want to achieve this merge statement using SSIS. I know this can be achieved using a merge join in SSIS but I am not sure if I can fit COALESCE statement anywhere. I wanted merge to happen between two tables only when the target table has NULL records.

```
MERGE TargetTable AS TARGET
USING SourceTable AS SOURCE

ON  ISNULL(TARGET.ColA, '')      = ISNULL(SOURCE.ColA, '')
    AND ISNULL(TARGET.ColB, '')  = ISNULL(SOURCE.ColB, '')

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
TARGET.ColC = COALESCE(TARGET.ColC, SOURCE.ColC)
TARGET.ColD = COALESCE(TARGET.ColD, SOURCE.ColD)
TARGET.ColE = COALESCE(TARGET.ColE, SOURCE.ColE)

WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET] THEN INSERT
(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE)

Values(SOURCE.ColA, SOURCE.ColB, SOURCE.ColC, SOURCE.ColD, SOURCE.ColE)
```

Comment: I am not sure WHAT you are doing, and WHY you are doing that! But, you can simply use derived column transformations before and after the merge join to achieve the `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE` functions used in the `MERGE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can simply use derived columns transformations to achieve the `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` functions.

There are two approaches:

1. Using [REPLACENULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replacenull-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
REPLACENULL(ColA,"")
```

2. Using the conditional operator [? :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) with the [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/isnull-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
ISNULL([ColA]) == True ? "" : [ColA]
```